# How to determine the program counter when decoding from assembly to machine code (Y86)?

Tags: assembly, machine-code, program-counter, y86

Im having trouble understanding how the address location is determined when decoding from assembly to Y86. In the example,

```
0x030          
0x030: 6300                     # xorq %rax , %rax
0x032: 50030001000000000000     # mrmovq 0x100(%rax ) , %rbx
0x03c: 50010002000000000000     # mrmovq 0x200(%rax ) , %rcx
```

how does the address location go from 0x030 to 0x032 to 0x03c? What is the equation for determining how much the location is increased by?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How many bytes are there in `6300`? Answer: 2 and `0x030 + 2 = 0x032`.
How many bytes are there in `50030001000000000000`? Answer: 10 and `0x032 + 10 = 0x03c`.

So you just count the number of bytes in the machine code and add to the previous address to get the next address.

Comment: Wow thank you so much! didn't think it was that simple.